# Replace require with import after switching to mjs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I switched from js file to mjs file, reading that this is the standard now, but i'm facing a noob problem, i used to have this code in mongoose.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

And in the entry point for my app i simply used:

```
require('./mongoose.js')
```

And all worked great, but now, with mjs file i need to use import instead of require, and i wish to understand how to do this properly, can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the mongoose configuration file using import as follows.
import './mongoose.js';